# Solution to stop getting "You've exceeded the limit of 100 jobs in the flex queue" for the batch class

Tags: apex, batch, apex-flex-queue

I am sending records in batches to a batch class.

**Code:**

```
BatchClass myBatchObject = new BatchClass(Trigger.new); 
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
```

I am getting the flex queue limit exceeding error on the second line above. After reading through various articles, I added a query check for the flex queue.

**Updated code:**

```
Integer flexQueueSize = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Holding' FOR UPDATE].size();
BatchClass myBatchObject = new BatchClass(Trigger.new); 
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
```

Do I need to add any other conditions as well? Also, if I am not wrong that won't cause any records to be lost. It would just put the records on hold until there is some space in the flex queue?

Comment: Why you are calling batch from Trigger, it seems like an antipattern. WHats the complete requirement.

Comment: so its an after insert trigger. After the custom object records are inserted, i am calling a batch class where I am sending the records. 

 if(Trigger.isInsert){  
            List<Customobject> records = Trigger.new;
            if(records[0].Contact__c == null && records[0].Home_Phone__c != null ){
                BatchClass myBatchObject = new BatchClass(Trigger.new); 
                Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);  
            }

Comment: Why not queuable ? or just scheduler that runs every 20 mins?

Comment: if you use Batch, it will run even for just single record, thus defeating the purpose of batch(bulk)

Comment: Queueable would be ideal, as others have said. Batchable isn't a modern solution to this problem.

Comment: If I use queueable class, would that process the records runtime? I was using batch class so that records could be processed on runtime.

Comment: Neither batch or Queuable will process record on runtime.

Comment: Ok so in the above code the records are not being sent runtime?

Comment: What are the benefits of using queueable vs batch class?

Comment: @Student This would answer everything.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex